# Post ajax request send a options request instead of a post

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax

I'm sending a post ajax request:

```
var responsehttpreq = {}
function createAndSendXmlHttpReq(){
    requestBody = {
        hostname: "prova",
        pathname: "prova",
        query: "prova",
        method: "prova"
    }
    console.log("Siamo nella funzione createAndSendXmlHttpReq")
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest()
    req.onreadystatechange = handler
    req.open("POST","http://localhost:8080",true)
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/json")
    req.send(JSON.stringify(requestBody))
}

function handler(){
    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
        console.log('----Risposta http------')
        console.log('Status Code:'+this.status)
        console.log('Dati:'+this.response)
        responsehttpreq = JSON.parse(this.response)
    }
}
```

The createAndSendXmlHttpReq() is called from a button in a html page, when I press the button I don't recive any response, but I can see from the developer console that an option request has been send, for the CORS option.
I have implemented a node js server that in case of an options request send a properly response:

```
if(req.method == "OPTIONS"){
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*")
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","POST")
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Request-Headers","content-type")
        res.end()
    }
```

The browser receive a 200 ok response from the server for the options request, but after that my ajax post request don'arrive to the server.
What is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*")
> ```

An `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in response to a [preflight OPTIONS request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests) can't use a wildcard.

The Console of your browser should tell you this.

You need to look at the `Origin` request header, determine if it is acceptable to you, then use it as the value of the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

Comment: @Alexandru-Ionut Mihai — I've rolled back your edit. The question is **reading** the request then **setting** the response… and I was quoting the code from the question. Don't edit other people's code except for formatting.

Comment: In the Origin header of my option request there is written "null", now my server is sending Access-Control-Allow-Origin: null, but after the response of the server no post request are fired :(